# cmake with multiple c files and header files

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

I have some trouble in using cmake.
I have five files as below.

```
list.c
list.h
spooky-c.c
spooky-c.h
main.c
```

And

1. `list.c` `#includes` `list.h`
2. `spooky-c.c` `#includes` `spooky-c.h`
3. `main.c` `#includes` `spooky-c.c` and `list.c`

I tried to make CMakeLists.txt as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Project_1 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.c")

add_executable(Project_1 ${SOURCES})
```

with following directory structure

1. `list.h` and `spooky-c.h` are in include/ folder
2. `list.c`, `spooky-c.c`, `main.c` are in src/ folder

But make doesn't work.
How should the CMakeLists.txt look like?

---

With the help of @Someprogrammerdude, I changed `main.c` to `#include` `list.h` and `spooky-c.h`.
cmake works as follows

```
(base) joo@joo:~/CLionProjects/Advanced_Programming/Project_1 (copy)/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/joo/CLionProjects/Advanced_Programming/Project_1 (copy)/build
```

But following error occurs.

```
(base) joo@joo:~/CLionProjects/Advanced_Programming/Project_1 (copy)/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target Project_1
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/Project_1.dir/src/list.c.o
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/Project_1.dir/src/spooky-c.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable Project_1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Project_1.dir/build.make:120: recipe for target 'Project_1' failed
make[2]: *** [Project_1] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Project_1.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project_1.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

@Someprogrammerdude
Thank you. I forgot to move `main.c` to src folder.
Now it works.

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? What happens when you run `cmake`? What happens when you run `make`? What errors do you get? Please create a [mcve] to show us, and copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output from the shown example.

Comment: And when you say that "main.c **includes** a.c and b.c" (emphasis mine), do you mean that the `main.c` source file actually `#include` the `a.c` and `b.c` source files? Don't `#include` source files!

Comment: @LPs The edit you made changing the included file names could be misleading, if that's the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I hope no,...but maybe you right.... Will see

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah `main.c` `#include` `a.c` and `b.c`.

Comment: You should change that before continuing. It is very bad practice to include C files. Should only include header files. And please respond to the first comment - define "doesn't work". What exactly are the errors.

Comment: @JoohyunKang And that's your problem. You build with those source files *twice*: Once as part of the `main.c` file due to the inclusion, and once separately as themselves by the make process. Then when the make process tries to link your program, you will get multiple definitions of all non-local symbols in those source files. As I said, don't include source file, include the header files instead.

Comment: @kaylum Okay. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Now the error is a completely different one, and it should be one that even a beginner should be able to guess how to solve: Create a `main` function.